Unlock Samsung S22+ with broken screen
I'm trying to unlock an S22+ with a broken screen.  I know the PIN number.  I tried connecting a USB-C hub to the phone, then connecting an HDMI monitor, a USB keyboard, and a USB mouse to the hub.  All I see on the monitor is a floating lock icon.  Occasionally for a split second I'll see the unlock screen, but then it goes back to the floating lock icon.  I've tried multiple key combinations including things like ENTER-PIN-ENTER, SPACEBAR-PIN-ENTER, etc.  None have worked.  I tried connecting the phone to a Windows PC and using the ADB command line tool.  It doesn't see the phone (not surprising since I never enabled debugging on it).  I tried using my Samsung account to unlock the phone, but that option was greyed out (possibly because I've already replaced the phone and linked a new phone to it's phone number).  I visited a Samsung Care center in person - they were no help.  I tried talking to a Samsung support person over chat - they were no help.  I even tried printing out a scaled template of the lock screen, cutting out holes for the numbers, taping it to the screen, and tapping in the PIN.  The phone may have unlocked, but on the HDMI monitor I still see the floating lock icon so I can't tell.
I also tried the USB-C hub on my new phone, a Samsung S24 Ultra.  I saw the floating lock icon.  Once I unlocked the phone and touched the pop-up to enable DEX, I was able to see the DEX screen.  I then killed DEX and I saw the mirrored screen.  I was able to use the keyboard to enter the pin with ENTER-PIN-ENTER, so I know the USB-C hub setup works.  But apparently I had to enable DEX first before I could use the USB keyboard to unlock the phone.
I can't figure out how to get past the floating lock icon to the PIN screen on the broken phone. Any suggestions?

In my tests with my Samsung Android 14 tablet pressing multiple times the delete key reliable opened the PIN entry dialog without accidentally entering a character (as space bar sometimes did). Then enter the PIN and press RETURN. If you enter the PIN too slow (more than 6-7 seconds delay between key presses) the PIN is erased and the screen goes dark and you have to start over.

Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried pressing the DEL key several times followed by the PIN and ENTER.  Didn't work.

I would recommend to only connect the keyboard without hub and HDMI (just to make sure Dex mode or the hub doesn't prevent you from entering the PIN) . Just the keyboard. Once the device has been unlocked you can change back to the hub.

I connected the keyboard via an OTG adapter.  I tried multiple key combinations with the PIN.  After each attempt I plugged in the USB-C hub with the monitor.  After all tests the floating lock icon was still being displayed.
